# Ansible get_url not registering return values

Tags: syntax, ansible

I am using Ansible 2.8.1 to download from Nexus.

I want to `register` a variable so that in subsequent tasks, I will know what file I downloaded by looking at `downloaded_file.dest`.

```
- name: Download assembly file to /my/server/location/
  get_url:
    url: https://nexus.mycompany.com/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository=repo-snapshots&group=group&name=name&sort=version&direction=desc
    validate_certs: no
    dest: /my/server/location/
    force: yes
    register: downloaded_file
```

But when running `ansible-playbook` 2.8.1

I get

`fatal: [myserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (get_url) module: register Supported parameters include: attributes, backup, checksum, client_cert, client_key, content, delimiter, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, force_basic_auth, group, headers, http_agent, mode, owner, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, sha256sum, src, timeout, tmp_dest, unsafe_writes, url, url_password, url_username, use_proxy, validate_certs"}`

So it's considering the `register` as a parameter to `get_url`. Is my syntax correct here? How do I get the return values from the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) is not a parameter of *get_url*.  It's a task's level directive.

Correct

```yaml
- name: Download assembly file to /my/server/location/
  get_url:
    url: https://nexus.mycompany.com/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository=repo-snapshots&group=group&name=name&sort=version&direction=desc
    validate_certs: no
    dest: /my/server/location/
    force: yes
  register: downloaded_file
```